# How to set my Nvim cursor as a vertical line in insert mode?

Tags: editor, neovim

When I'm editing in normal mode in Nvim I get the cursor as a block.
[image: block cursor shape]

That's fine. However, when I enter insert mode I get the same result.

[image: block cursor in insert mode]

I want the cursor shape to stay as a line in insert mode, anyone can help me?

Comment: By the way I'm using the xfce4-terminal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be modified through `guicursor`. The default value(`n-v-c-sm:block,i-ci-ve:ver25,r-cr-o:hor20`) should be fine.

Comment: Thanks, this completely solved my problem :)